# Ag-Grid-React Extending line formatting beyond fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid-react

So I'm making a web app using react and part of the app is an ag-Grid table. The table is working fine but the problem I'm having is that when the fields end horizontally, the table is a complete blank of white. I want it to continue its line breaks a and formatting past all the fields.

I haven't actually tried anything because it's my first time using react and documentation online is pretty poor for ag-Grid styling and formatting specifics.

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id4Wh.png)

...This image shows the red (How I want it all styled) and the green (How the dead space is currently styled).